# Limits of gravity?

Tags: gravity, cosmology

Is there a limit to the pull of gravity?
Will there ever be a point where we can say that the gravity of object A does not affect us? ie is equal to zero.
PS: Sorry if i dont make sense, i do not have a physics background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Newton's theory of gravitation, the gravitational force between two objects of mass diminishes rapidly with distance between them, but is never zero.

[image: gravforce]

Newtonian gravity emerges as the limit of [General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) so the answer is the same even in the more general framework.

Comment: so does it mean that literally everything in the universe is pulling us at different force ?

Comment: @BhagyeshChaudhari Yes, but if you put in numbers, not measurably from the distant ones. The moon's pull can be measured, the sun's and the planets  a tiny influence , and one can ignore the rest.

Comment: but why people say that there are many equations for gravity? check this link, and read the first line of the post.
http://www.universetoday.com/56157/gravity-equation/

Comment: There will be many equations, but derivable from the basic newtonian equations ( for low masses and energies relative to galactic conditions.)